# Saving pdf with Date and name

Tags: datetime, shell-escape

I have a file called quotes.tex. When I run it, it creates my quote for that date for a certain customer.
I now want to save this quote.pdf automatically as `date_customer_quote`. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}

%%% select the required data %%%%
\newcommand{\shop} {George's} 
\newcommand{\product}{Green Apples}

%%%%%%% DON'T ALTER FROM HERE ONWARDS (except spacing)%%%%

\usepackage{graphicx}       %% allow graphics

\usepackage{xcolor}                   %% allow colour
\definecolor{teal}{RGB}{76,177,155}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.4}

\usepackage[textwidth=450pt, textheight=680pt,top=3cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry} %margins


\usepackage{datetime} % dates - my altered dates below
\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR} %just month written and Year

\newdateformat{normal}{%
  \longdate \ordinaldate{\THEDAY} \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR} %normal date

\newcommand\twodigits[1] {\ifnum#1<10 0#1\else #1\fi}
\newdateformat{quoteNo}{%
   \THEYEAR--\twodigits{\THEMONTH}--\twodigits{\THEDAY} } % digit date for quote no.


\usepackage{advdate} % quote expiry

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % don't hyphenate



\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % never indent first line

 \normal \today \\
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{center}
\scshape{Chris' \product \, Box \par}
\vspace{0.2cm}
    {\Large{Quote for \shop} \par}
\vspace{0.1cm}
{\large Quote No: \quoteNo \today --1 \par}
\vspace{0.2cm}
%image
\end{center}
\vfill
g

\newpage


{\hrulefill
\bigbreak

\begin{center}
\textbf{\huge{\color{light-gray} Price:  \qquad  \$\, 8,345 \quad plus GST}}
\end{center}

\bigbreak
\hrulefill}

\color{teal} {%
\subsubsection*{Options Included In Price:}
a

}
\color{black}
\vspace{0.4cm} % adjust spacing here
\hrulefill

\subsubsection*{Quoted price also includes:}

 \begin{itemize}
\item 1 year warranty 
\end{itemize}

\vspace{-0.4cm} % adjust spacing here
\hrulefill %remove if necessary

\color{light-gray}{%
\subsubsection*{\underline{OPTIONAL ITEMS AVAILABLE}}
\vspace{0.4cm} % adjust spacing here
}

\textbf{Quotation expiry:}\normal{\AdvanceDate[28] \today}

\bigbreak
\hrulefill
\bigbreak

If you wish to place an order, would like additional options included in the quote or require any further details please contact me.\\

Kind regards,\\
 \bigbreak
\color{teal}{
Chris}

\end{document}
```

In my example, I would like to save as `200420_George_quote.pdf`. Can that be done? How? (And please, if you try to explain something with `write18`, please explain the full code as I tried and failed)